# How can I check the existence of a language before set of its session in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

*Hi. I Currently using this function in `routes`*

```
Route::get('locale/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    \Session::put('locale', $locale);
    return redirect()->back();
});
```

*for changing the language.*

*I want to check the existence of a **language** before the set of its `SESSION` like this.*

```
Route::get('locale/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    if(!exist($locale)){
         \Session::put('locale', 'en');
    }
    else{
         \Session::put('locale', $locale);    
    }
    return redirect()->back();
});
```

*How can I Create a function like the above function?*

*the above function is an example and it is **incorrect**.*

Comment: use `if (!Session::has('locale`))` then set `en` no need of else condition

Comment: this is correct for all

Comment: thanks. this isn't helpful for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whether or not this is necessary is to be determined.  Laravel falls back to the default language if the given locale is missing completely or just missing that specific identifier.

I can think of an easy way to check if a specific locale does have any translations:

```
if (file_exists(resource_path("lang/$locale"))) {
   // Locale directory exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `Lang::hasForLocale()` if you're sure the is a file always present in each language. Eg: if you always `some-keys.php` in every locale folder, you can do

```
Use Lang;

if (Lang::hasForLocale('some-keys', $locale)) {
   //
}
```